# How can I set the ~/.aws/credentials on heroku?

Tags: python, bash, heroku, amazon-s3, environment-variables

I'm deploying my application on Heroku and I'm trying to read files from s3 buckets, but I can't find good references about how to set the ~/.aws/credentials on Heroku context;

I'm working all day on it and trying to figure out how to solve this problem

In my local environment, I'm using the following configuration to make it works:
[image]

Someone could help me on how to set these values on Heroku, please?!?!?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: Hey jordanm, thanks for the link but I read it a lot and I don't know what's going wrong with my tries; I think that I solved the problem by simply setting the aws_access_key_id AND key directly through the Config Vars

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command in your local terminal

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={ACCESS} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={SECRET}
```

I have used this for AWS Dynamodb with Heroku and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

[default]
aws_access_key_id=[yourkeyhere]
aws_secret_access_key=[yoursecretekeyhere]
[admin]
aws_access_key_id=[yourkeyhere]
aws_secret_access_key=[yoursecretekeyhere]

I have set as above and my site is working fine.

Comment: The link to your website isn't necessary here (see how the other answer is phrased). I'd suggest removing the link as it's unnecessary promotion, which is not permitted on this site.